# How to dynamically sort table data with keyset pagination?

Tags: database, postgresql, pagination

I have this table

```
users(
  id uuid,
  cpf string,
  name string,
  email string,
  admin boolean
);
```

The following are indexed: cpf, name, admin.

When I first load this data from the API, it would be ordered by admin (admin users would be on top). However, since i'm using keyset pagination, I look for the last id in the data set and query again (where it has an X, it is dynamic):

```
        SELECT  id,
            name,
            cpf,
            email,
            Coalesce(admin, '0') as admin   
        FROM 
            users
        WHERE 
            cpf >= '' (empty for the first query, then it would be the last one in the first data set)
        AND (
                name like 'X%'
            OR
                email like 'X%'
        )
        ORDER BY 
            X (admin, name, cpf) 
        ASC (or desc, depending on what was chosen)
        LIMIT 
            X
```

So here I have my first data set, loaded fine, but when I would change the page, it would look for the cpfs that are bigger than the actual, they are not the actual next page. How would I fix this? Considering the user can choose wheter he order by: admin, name and cpf? The same column that orders need to be the row with the last row? And how this would work if I order by admin, since it is a boolean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For keyset pagination, if you want to order by `(admin, name, cpf)`, the condition must be

```
WHERE (admin, name, cpf) > (max_admin, max_name, max_cpf)
```

where the `max_*` values are the last values returned by the previous query.

Comment: Wouldn't this lower the indexes performance? (they are all single column indexes). Also, they are ordered once, ex: https://quasar.dev/vue-components/table#Example--Synchronizing-with-server (this is what i'll be using)

Comment: You need a multicolumn index to make keyset pagination efficient.

Comment: Oh, so I index it int by the most used order, correctly? And would I be sorting by the three or only one at the time? Anyway, thank you very much, helped a lot!

Comment: Also, any limitation on how many columns can I use in the composite index?

Comment: The index has to be defined exactly like the `ORDER BY` clause. Index rows are limited to something above 1000 bytes, but if you are coming close to that, reduce the number of columns.

Comment: But like, what if I will order by admin, then only name or cpf? It's ordering at the same time, will it be the same?

Comment: I don't understand. You can only order one way in one query, not in different ways. If you have different possible orderings, you need to play the same gabe for each of these.

Comment: Did you checked the quasar table? Everytime you click in one ordering, it would query, based on what was sent (direction, input, the key that will order), and load it all again. So as I can see, I would have to do dynamic queries, right?

Comment: Quasar what? There is no way to change the ordering *while* you are paging short of starting over.

Comment: Quasar framework tables (https://quasar.dev/vue-components/table#Example--Synchronizing-with-server) in the "Syncronizing with server" section. It's that behaviour I want to achieve. So I cannot use the indexes to reset the query (with a filter or new ordering) ?

Comment: Could you destruct this query right there? I know this (a, b) > (c, d) translates to: 
(a > c or (a = c and b > d)). How would this behave? (Also, with mixed orders it is different aswell) WHERE (admin desc, name asc, cpf asc) > (max_admin, max_name, max_cpf).

Comment: @NataJdaCOliveira Right, it is "lexicographical order": `(a, b, c) < (x, y, z)` is the same as `a < x OR (a = x AND b < y) OR (a = x AND b = y AND c < z)`.